# "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0" Error

Tags: android, spinner, pug

I am developing a Jade Multiagent System that sends messages between devices through a jade server, everything worked fine until I needed to add some Spinners, im also getting an ArrayList object from another class through an interface. Any thoughts on what Im doing wrong? Heres some of the code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ventana_enviar_mensaje);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    usuario = intent.getStringExtra("usuario");

    Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_enviar);
    bt.setOnClickListener(bt_enviar_pregunta_OnClick);

    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_agregar);
    bt.setOnClickListener(bt_agregar_OnClick);

    //Register to interface class
    try{
        interfaz = MicroRuntime.getAgent(usuario).getO2AInterface(Interfaz.class);}
    catch (StaleProxyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ControllerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

            //Put some values into spinners
    Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_categoria);

    adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,0);
    adaptador.add("Cat1");
    adaptador.add("Cat2");
    adaptador.add("Cat3");
    adaptador.add("Cat4");
    sp.setAdapter(adaptador);
    adaptador.clear();

    sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_tipo);
    adaptador.add("Tipo1");
    adaptador.add("Tipo2");
    adaptador.add("Tipo3");
    adaptador.add("Tipo4");
    sp.setAdapter(adaptador);
    adaptador.clear();
    //Retrieve the list from another class
    ArrayList activos = new ArrayList();
    try {
        activos = interfaz.ObtenerActivos();
        sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_destinatarios);
        Iterator it = activos.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            adaptador.add(it.next().toString());
        }           
        sp.setAdapter(adaptador);
    } catch (FIPAException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This can happen when a resource is not defined for a particular device configuration. Do you have any qualified resource directories (`res/values-hdpi`, etc.)? Also, what line is generating the exception?

Comment: It breaks after finishing onCreate

Comment: And no I dont think I have any "qualified resource directories", kind of newbie to android here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replaced:

```
adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,0);
```

with:

```
adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

My bad